# How do I make responsive 3 rows with images

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem that I my grid looks quite different on mobile devices, meanwhile on PCs, it looks just like I wanted, and I realized that it's a grid's issue, but I don't really know how to fix it since it gives different results all the time. Here's the code I use:

```css
.offer .card-img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.offer {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 130ms ease;
}

.card-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.01);
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container pt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <figure>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card offer">
          <div class="card-img" style="background: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(145).jpg') no-repeat center center" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <h5 class="mx-auto">Classic</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </figure>
      <figure> 
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card offer">
            <div class="card-img" style="background: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(145).jpg') no-repeat center center" alt=""></div>
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h5 class="mx-auto">Classic</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </figure>
      </div>
     
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <figure >
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card offer">
              <div class="card-img" style="background: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Original/img%20(145).jpg')  no-repeat right center" alt=""></div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <h5 class="mx-auto">Classic</h5>
                <p class="card-text"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[and this is how it looks on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzk1d.jpg)

but when i resize my screen, it changes to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdBR4.jpg)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Of course it looks like that on resized screen when you have justify-content-center on third div. Maybe you should explain what do you want as I can't really figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using flexbox on the parent element for the layout.

Desktop:

```
.parent{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
}
.image{
width: 45%;
height: auto;
}
```

Mobile:

```
.parent{
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
}
.image{
width: 100%;
}
```

Flexbox is an amazing tool for layouts and I'd highly suggest looking into:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope it Helps! :)

Comment: How can I use it in my code? what should I put as .parent meanwhile i'm using card to show images? sorry, i'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

On the third image, `<div class="row justify-content-center">` will make it always centered no matter what,